# Add menu and menu item in grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails

I want to redirect user after login to homepage. There I need to add menu and submenu and menu item. I have to use grails 1.3.7. But I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please suggest me how to do it ? Any code example, any link please. I need it very very much.

Comment: Are you using the spring security plugin?

Comment: @marko No. Even I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Ok here's what you should do. Read and watch this: http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/ That will cover login and it will show you how simple it is to control content based when a user is logged in.